# Imported FBX Materials/Textures Randomly Renamed

Tags: materials, import

Blender on one of my laptops (both Windows 10) is adding a numerical suffix to all my materials/textures of .fbx files I import. I tested thoroughly on Blender 2.78a reset to factory defaults, but one computer imports the same .fbx always with added numbers.

> e.g. "Skin_Body.001" should be "Skin_Body"
>
> See below attachments.

This is a major pain when the .fbx is a rigged character with dozens of materials, and each must have their suffix deleted in order to export properly. Is there a setting I might be missing to cause this?

Normal:

[image]

Not Normal:

[image]

Comment: I would expect that along with eye_diffuse.001, you have an eye_diffuse material. This is expected in Blender with any material or object with an identical name.

Comment: It renames both the material and textures after checking.

Why does it do it on one computer and not the other though? 

I spent two days trying to figure out why my models wouldn't import to iClone Character Creator, and it turns out it was this.